# Show checkbox onhovering over a row of a table

Tags: interaction-design, multi-selection, batch-actions, checkbox

My team is working on a Saas product. we have a table design where we displays actions onhover (we use this approach throught the product)

we are adding a new feature where the user can select multiple rows and perform an action.We decided to use checkbox for this feature.

my team wants the checkbox to appear onhover rather than being displayed all the time. I couldn't find a single product doing it in this manner. Personally I think the checkbox must be visible all the time

What do you think?
Have the checkbox visible or show it onhovering over the row

Comment: Although I would advise against only showing checkboxes on hover, you can compare the use between both options if you compare Outlook vs. Gmail. Outlook shows checkboxes when you hover over emails, and will show checkboxes for all emails if you select at least one email. Gmail, on the other hand, always shows checkboxes. It's a place to start, good luck :)

Comment: How are touch screen and keyboard users using the actions?

Comment: For touch screen we can set a trigger to activate the checkbox. eg: long pressing on a row can activate the checkbox